# SQL server exception : when using jdbc connection to retrieve data

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I use `callable` interface of Java and try to read the output variable value of a stored procedure written in SQL server.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Get_Project_Name_Test] 
    @project_id int,
    @project_name varchar(150) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @project_name = (SELECT Name from Project where Project_Id = @project_id)
END
GO
```

Here `@project_id` is input variable and `@project_name` is output variable. I want to read this value of the output variable from Java application. When I run the code I get a sql exception.

It says:

> The formal parameter "@project_id" was not declared as an OUTPUT
>   parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

Actually, this is not an output parameter. `@project_id` is the input parameter used to retrieve the result.

Java code which used to call this stored procedure

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call Get_Project_Name_Test(?)}");
cstmt.setInt(1, 148);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
cstmt.executeQuery();
String x = cstmt.getString(1);
System.out.println(x);
```

How can I figure out the cause of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

be

```
 cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this. But it didn't work. I got the exception "**SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of range.**"

Comment: That's because you are only passing one parameter to the stored procedure, needs two; Get_Project_Name_Test(?, ?)

Comment: yes got it... Thanks a lot. It works fine. I was under the impression that we have to provide only input parameters when calling the stored procedure. I got that part now. It works. Thanks again.